# Why does the shortcut I created change to NDOF Fit

Tags: shortcut

I changed the shortcut for Frame Selected from Number . to Shift F and after I saved the project the shortcut changed to NDOF Fit and I can't change it or remove the shortcut. The only way I can change it is to reset the default settings but that removes everything including my project.

How do I create a short cut for Frame Selected when it says NDOF Fit.

Answer (score 0):

*Blender Preferences > 3D View > 3D View Global > View Selected > Keyboard F*

[image]